# Sublime Text2 keeps crashing

Tags: sublimetext2

I installed SublimeText 2 yesterday, installed package, and just a few plugins, emmet, snippets, boilerplates etc, nothing major.
When i closed and opened again after a save it crashed, so i decided to re-install again and i got the following message

[image: Error messgage]

It wont let me reinstall again, as far as i know i have deleted everything, but evidently not.
Would be grate full for help. because its a beautiful piece of kit!

Comment: You obviously left the settings in your %appdata% folder. There seems to be syntax error in the file pointed to you, so you either correct it, or remove the whole folder and reinstall again.

Comment: Try deleting the `Sublime Text 2` folder from AppData and then reinstall.

Comment: cheers guys, fixed now, dozzy mistake by me, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open that file in notepad or something, there must be a JSON syntax error in that file that is causing it. Fix it.

```
User/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

If it doesn't work just delete the file/whole User directory and install sublime text again.

Comment: ah thanks mate, silly me, i was setting preferences for a shortkey for snippets incorrectly, must of saved it by mistake, fixed now, thank you sir.